# Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [40000]

Tags: hive, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I am submitting a job in oozie for hive, but after submitting its shows 
Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [40000] .

Below is my hive-ste.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <!-- Hive Configuration can either be stored in this file or in the hadoop configuration files  -->
  <!-- that are implied by Hadoop setup variables.                                                -->
  <!-- Aside from Hadoop setup variables - this file is provided as a convenience so that Hive    -->
  <!-- users do not have to edit hadoop configuration files (that may be managed as a centralized -->
  <!-- resource).                                                                                 -->
  <!-- Hive Execution Parameters -->

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
<value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
<description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
<value>false</value>
<description>enable or disable the hive client authorization</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.security.authorization.createtable.owner.grants</name>
<value>ALL</value>
<description>the privileges automatically granted to the owner whenever a table gets created.
An example like "select,drop" will grant select and drop privilege to the owner of the table</description>
</property> 



</configuration>
```

---

hql file.
select * from test limit 10;
My work flow.xml

Comment: <workflow-app name="hive_test" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="hive_test"/>
    <action name="hive_test">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
              <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
            <script>test.hql</script>
        </hive>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>  <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>

Comment: I am using CDH5 having hive ver:0.13.1

Comment: The issue got resolved by putting column name and DB name with table name.

Comment: can you explain us how it was fixed? What was the exact issue?